# Bleach and html5lib incompatible with tensorboard

Tags: html, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorboard, bleach

While installing tensorflow I received the following error :

distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed.
which I tried resolving by executing the following command

```
conda install -c anaconda msgpack-python
pip install msgpack
```

However it then gave the following error which I am not able to resolve

tensorboard 1.8.0 has requirement bleach==1.5.0, but you'll have bleach 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
tensorboard 1.8.0 has requirement html5lib==0.9999999, but you'll have html5lib 1.0.1 which is incompatible.

How to update bleach and html5lib so that it is compatible with tensorboard?

Ubuntu 18.04